# What do you call someone who either borrows money, or receives equity funding?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Someone who lends money, or otherwise purchases equity, is called an *investor*. The money he is spending are his *investments*.

What do you call the person on the receiving end of this arrangement?

Comment: Surely money you've lent to someone can be considered an investment though.

Comment: investment vehicle: http://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/investmentvehicle.asp

Comment: I guess "in general" you'd say that's the entrepreneur or the start-up.  So, you can imagine a large meeting or talk, and someone would say "all you entrepreneurs sit over this side, all investors this side please" or the like.

Answer (score 10):

As someone involved in the venture-capital space, I would use different words depending on the scenario in question.

- Someone who receives money in exchange for a promise to pay it back later is called a [***borrower***](http://www.investorwords.com/7518/borrower.html)<sup>1</sup>, and the person making the loan is the ***lender***:

> A person that has applied, met specific requirements, and received a monetary loan from a lender.

- Someone who receives money in exchange for equity is called an [***investee***](http://www.investorwords.com/11654/investee.html)<sup>1</sup>, and the person investing the money is called an ***investor***.

> A company or entity in which an investor makes a direct investment.

- You could also use *investor* to describe a person who loans money, in the case of a loan. But I would probably always call the recipient a borrower, not an investee: the goal of the investment is very different in the two cases.

<sup>1</sup> [Investorwords.](http://www.investorwords.com/)

Comment: It is *not* enough to link quotes, citations must be properly attributed. [What to do about missing source attributions?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/what-to-do-about-missing-source-attributions) etc. there are many other posts on this issue.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I think you got me in between edits. I wanted to format the link a little better because the original editor's sentence was poorly formatted, didn't actually link anywhere, didn't reference the citation in question, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The receiving end of the arrangement would be the "**[investee](http://www.investorwords.com/11654/investee.html)**". From www.investorwords.com:

> A company or entity in which an investor makes a direct investment